# Calling a stored procedure from a third party app but it does not execute, but no errors are returned. What can I do to troubleshoot?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure being called remotely from a third party application. The stored procedure executes properly when called locally, but does not execute when called remotely. By locally I mean, if I right click and choose Execute; or if I enter `exec sp_EBRRecipeMove` from a query window.  Even though it doesn't execute when called remotely, no errors are returned.

Backstory: this stored procedure is part of a sequence of stored procedures that gets called from a customer's API. API calls `sp_1`. `sp_1` calls `sp_2`, `sp3`, and `sp_4`. If there are no errors returned, `sp_1` calls `sp_EBRRecipeMove`. All of this in an effort to error check and move setpoints from one database to another.

I have sprinkled in `RAISERROR`'s throughout this script to help me understand how far it gets through the script. SQL Log indicates that it is progressing through the script, yet the values never update and the values from the original tables never migrate to the destination tables.

Thus far, the end user's application (PHP I believe) causes this behavior, and a simple Java app to call the stored procedure causes it also. I can execute this manually/locally without issue. I won't have access to the PHP code.

The end user's application does call other stored procedures from the same database with success.

In an effort to reduce the chance of a DB permissions issue, I've given the user that is used to connect remotely sysadmin access.

I have verified that all of instances of the `RecipeID` column in the database and associated variables are all `INT`. In the destination table, this column is `Int NOT NULL`, but in the other (EBR) tables I allow Null values since the value may not be populated.

UPDATE: I've since verified that the third party app is not calling the stored procedure via transaction.  From the Oracle Database they are using, it is a simple Call.

Using the hints already posted, I did significant troubleshooting as was able to successfully execute the stored procedure by calling it from a third party Java App.  However, when implementing the changes on the customer's setup, the commands do not execute.  I commented out the code and tried executing 1 command at a time with the Try... Catch around each.  Try... Catch is not returning any errors, but the commands are not executing.  Is there a special permission or setting in the tables that will allow remote execution of Insert, Delete, and Update commands?  Any help or hints is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE2:  From another stackoverflow post related to Deletes by @Remus Rusanu, I can provide the following information regarding the cases why Deletes or other commands might not execute and hopefully post my amended code tomorrow -

•the DELETE does not execute (logic flow control issue, it takes the other IF branch...)
[This is not the case, I have RAISERRORs just before and just after the command that log reasonable information given the inputs (except that the Delete didn't happen)]

•the DELETE executes but does not affect any rows (WHERE clause or JOIN problem)
[This is not the case, or at least seemingly, since I can take the Delete...Where and put it in a query and execute.  I'm not using any Joins.]

•the DELETE executes and errors and the error is silently suppressed (error handling problem)
[This should not be the problem as I commented out the entire code except 1 Delete...Where statement and put a Try...Catch directly around it]

•the DELETE executes but the effect is rolled back (transaction management problem)
[This is not the case because I am not using transactions and the calling client is not using a transaction.]

•the DELETE executes but the effect is compensated by app (application logic problem)
[I may not understand this properly, but I'll offer this: This shouldn't be the case since I commented out all surrounding code.  Also, the client is using a simple CALL command from Oracle.]

•the DELETE does not execute because a previous error stops the request (again error handling problem)
[This shouldn't be the case because I can see that the RAISERROR logs reasonable information just before and just after the Delete statement.]

•the DELETE executes but your verification is incorrect (PBCAK)
[This is not the case since the row is not deleting.  A Select statement of the table indicates the row is still intact after executing the stored procedure.]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_EBRRecipeMove]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @Version smallint;
    Declare @CheckedOutID tinyint;
    Declare @AbleToSave bit;
    Declare @EquipName varchar(80);
    Declare @RcpName varchar(80);
    Declare @EquipID tinyint;
    Declare @status int;
    Declare @prRcpName varchar(80);
    Declare @prVersion smallint;
    Declare @tmprows int;
    Declare @recipeid int;
    Declare @tmpid int
    Declare @groupid tinyint;
    Declare @rcpcomment varchar(200);
    Declare @prrcpcomment varchar(200);
    Declare @savedatim datetime;
    Declare @saveuser varchar(80);
    Declare @approvaldatim datetime;
    Declare @approvaluser varchar(80);
    Declare @deactdatim datetime;
    Declare @deactuser varchar(80);
    Declare @existingRecID int;
    DECLARE @ErrorSave int
        SET @ErrorSave = 0


    -- Select recipe info from EBRRecipeHeader table
    SELECT @RcpName=recipename
    FROM EBRRecipeHeader

    -- Select recipe info from prRecipeHeader table
    SELECT @prRcpName=RecipeName
    FROM prRecipeHeader
    WHERE RecipeName = @RcpName 


        set @Version = 1;       
        set @status = 3; 
        set @groupid = 1;
        set @savedatim = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        set @saveuser = 'EBR'
        set @approvaldatim = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        set @approvaluser = 'EBR'
        set @CheckedOutID = 0;     


        if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            begin
                INSERT INTO dbo.prRecipeHeader(
                    GroupID,
                    Status,
                    RecipeName,
                    Version,
                    RecipeComment,
                    SaveDateTime,
                    SaveUser,
                    ApprovalDateTime,
                    ApprovalUser,
                    DeactivateDateTime,
                    DeactivateUser,
                    CheckedOutID
                    ) VALUES (
                    @groupid,
                    @status,
                    @RcpName,
                    @Version,
                    @rcpcomment,
                    @savedatim,
                    @saveuser,
                    @approvaldatim,
                    @approvaluser,
                    @deactdatim,
                    @deactuser,
                    @CheckedOutID        
                    )

                end 

        ELSE 
            begin

                DELETE FROM prRecipeHeader
                WHERE RecipeName = @RcpName 

                INSERT INTO dbo.prRecipeHeader(
                    GroupID,
                    Status,
                    RecipeName,
                    Version,
                    RecipeComment,
                    SaveDateTime,
                    SaveUser,
                    ApprovalDateTime,
                    ApprovalUser,
                    DeactivateDateTime,
                    DeactivateUser,
                    CheckedOutID
                    ) VALUES (
                    @groupid,
                    @status,
                    @RcpName,
                    @Version,
                    @rcpcomment,
                    @savedatim,
                    @saveuser,
                    @approvaldatim,
                    @approvaluser,
                    @deactdatim,
                    @deactuser,
                    @CheckedOutID        
                    )

            end --if <>0


    select @recipeid = RecipeID from prRecipeHeader where prRecipeHeader.RecipeName = @RcpName;


declare @recipeidText as varchar(8)
set @recipeidText = convert(varchar(8), @recipeid)
RAISERROR (@recipeidtext,10,1) WITH LOG     
RAISERROR ('RecipeID before Globals',10,1) WITH LOG  



    UPDATE  EBRRecipeGlobals    SET EBRRecipeGlobals.recipeid = @recipeid;

set @recipeidText = convert(varchar(8), @recipeid)
RAISERROR (@recipeidtext,10,1) WITH LOG     
RAISERROR ('RecipeID before global insert',10,1) WITH LOG  



    INSERT INTO prRecipeGlobals SELECT * FROM EBRRecipeGlobals where EBRRecipeGlobals.recipeid = @recipeid;
    DELETE From EBRRecipeGlobals Where EBRRecipeGlobals.recipeid = @recipeid;

set @recipeidText = convert(varchar(8), @recipeid)
RAISERROR (@recipeidtext,10,1) WITH LOG     
RAISERROR ('RecipeID after globals insert, before steps',10,1) WITH LOG  


    UPDATE EBRRecipeSteps SET EBRRecipeSteps.RecipeID = @recipeid;

set @recipeidText = convert(varchar(8), @recipeid)
RAISERROR (@recipeidtext,10,1) WITH LOG     
RAISERROR ('RecipeID before steps insert',10,1) WITH LOG  

    INSERT INTO prRecipeSteps SELECT * FROM EBRRecipeSteps where EBRRecipeSteps.RecipeID = @recipeid;
    DELETE From EBRRecipeSteps Where EBRRecipeSteps.RecipeID = @recipeid;



    DELETE FROM EBRRecipeHeader 

end
```

Comment: Is the client running this inside a transaction from their code that gets rolled back? You might want to run a trace on this process and see what is happening. As a side note you should avoid the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Use a profiler trace to see what commands the app is sending.  (or not sending).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Quick comments: `@@ROWCOUNT = 0` does not work the way you expect. It's always going to not equal 0 because of the `SET` you do above it. Use `@prRcpName is null` instead. Also, does `prRecipeSteps` have a foreign key to `prRecipeHeader` and does it cascade if you delete from the latter, if so? Because if not, given your `@@rowcount` issue, you could test on SSMS fine, then run the same test again and it fail because you can't delete from `prRecipeHeader` without deleting from `prRecipeSteps` first.

Comment: @SeanLange - I will confirm with the client if they are using a transaction.  In the future, I will not use the sp_ prefix.

Comment: @TabAlleman   Although I upgraded my SQL from Express to Enterprise, the Full Configuration Tools did not install.  It seems non-trivial to uninstall and reinstall, but in the future I will be sure to select all of the Configuration Tools when installing.

Comment: @JasonWhitish  This is a really great tip and I'll let you know how it goes.  I'm going to use the Try...Catch you mention below to see if the @@Rowcount causes an error.  Thank you for clearly explaining the use of Try...Catch.  I've read a lot about it, but really wasn't sure to implement.  I checked in my DB, if I delete a row from prRecipeHeader, the rows in prRecipeSteps with the corresponding RecipeID also delete.  If I delete from Steps first, the header row does not delete.

Comment: Good to hear about how prRecipeHeader and prRecipeSteps interact. That means they have a cascading foreign key, so that if you delete from the referenced table (prRecipeHeader), it will also delete from the referencing table.

Comment: I think you can simply update your existing installation rather than uninstall + reinstall.   It's still not trivial, but it will be worth it.  I can't imagine life without profiler.

Comment: @JasonWhitish I used the Try Catch referenced below to troubleshoot and it was a HUGE help.  I ran 1 command with the rest of the code commented out; if it was successful, I uncommented the next command and put the Try Catch around that.  The @@ROWCOUNT was causing trouble.  I used your suggestion to try the IS NULL instead and I'm having success executing the stored procedure from a free Java Tool called Execute Query over the network.  I consider this a success because initially it was failing on this tool also.  I am hopeful that I can deploy on the customer's system today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I would recommend doing that will hopefully save you a good deal of time.

The first one is to try to capture the return status of the proc when you call it from `sp_1`. Something like this:

```
declare @i int, @e nvarchar(20);

EXEC @i = sp_EBRRecipeMove

SELECT @e = N'RETURN STATUS = ' + cast(@i as nvarchar(4));

RAISERROR(@e, 10, 1) WITH LOG;
```

If you look and see that the return status was anything other than 0, then the proc is definitely failing somewhere.

The second thing you can do, and you can do concurrently with the above, is to add a `TRY..CATCH` block to your code in `sp_EBRRecipeMove`. Right now, because you do not have any error handling, the proc keeps trying to move through the steps it has, regardless of how successful they are. So it becomes kind of hard to determine where exactly your problem is. The `TRY..CATCH` will jump to the `CATCH` as soon as you have an error.

So:

```
BEGIN TRY
    --(rest of code from proc)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 10,1) WITH LOG
END CATCH
```

It's worth noting that you may really want to consider a transaction here, in addition to doing a `TRY..CATCH` to make sure your data is inserted, or not, as a set. Right now, part of your changes could make it in but not all, which could also be causing you testing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQL Profiler, Try...Catch, RAISERRORS, and being onsite with the enduser team of programs, we were able to trouble shoot down as follows: 
The Calling API to the stored procedure was not using a transaction; however, when they close the connection between Caller and the SQL DB in which the SP resides, we get 2 x messages of if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK.  By closing the connection, the commands were being rolled back.

At first when we saw the @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK, we investigated Implicit/Explicit Transactions and found that it might be best to use transactions in my SP with Try...Catch which we did, but we found that we still had @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK.

Then, we separated out the stored procedure which we thought was the problem and executed it separately.  We found that the initial portion of the stored procedure executed without rollback or error (not surprising).  Then, without closing the connection, we called the second part of the stored procedure (that we assumed was the problem) and it did not rollback or error (this was surprising).  The system did not rollback until the connection was closed.